# How to align elements in three columns, even when resizing

Tags: html, css, sass

**Desired outcome:** I have three columns. I need them to be all the same width, as well as text and buttons to be on the same level in all three of them.

**Problem:** Depending on the number of words, columns become wider and buttons start to jump when text is resizing, and all three texts are resizing on a different points. I need to prevent that. How can I achieve this?

**HTML:**

```
<section class="sub-offer">
      <div class="offer-container">
        <div class="offer-up">
          <h2>Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png/09f/fff" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="offer-down">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a
            rerum sapiente odit porro obcaecati fugit, maxime modi veritatis
            quis!
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="more-btn">
          <a href="#">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="offer-container">
        <div class="offer-up">
          <h2>Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png/09f/fff" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="offer-down">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi
            perspiciatis voluptas qui iste, voluptatem atque ab rerum illum quia
            incidunt odio?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="more-btn">
          <a href="#">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="offer-container">
        <div class="offer-up">
          <h2>Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png/09f/fff" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="offer-down">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
            vitae aut fugit dicta repellendus dolorem, quam, accusamus hic nemo
            ullam quod porro atque error?
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="more-btn">
          <a href="#">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.sub-offer {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;

  .offer-container {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #2e2e3b, #0f1519);
  }

  h2 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 4.3em;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
  }

  p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  }

  a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: white;
    margin: 3em 0 2.5em 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;

    &:hover {
      background: #e5e5e5;
    }
  }
}
```

**How they look now:**

[image]

Comment: `CSS-Grid` or `Flexbox` will solve it for you. CSS-Grid: `section.sub-offer { display: grid; grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr); }` Flexbox: `section.sub-offer { display: flex; } .offer-container { width: calc(100% / 3); }`

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what you mean by 'text ... to be on the same level'. Are you saying that however much text is in each one, whatever the aspect ratio of the image, the texts must all start at the same vertical level. And similarly all the buttons must be at the same vertical level?

Comment: @tacoshy great, it is indeed solved an issue with the width, thanks! However I also need to align elements inside

Comment: @AHaworth yeah, I mean that I do not want buttons to be on the different starting points as it is now on the picture. Now they jump bcs text has different number of words. I need all buttons to be positioned on the same level, so they look kinda aligned with each other. And when they resize, I want them to resize together, still keeping this visual alignment. Hope that makes sense...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. To give all three columns the **same width** I've used what @tacoshy recommended in the comments: `section.sub-offer { display: flex; } .offer-container { width: calc(100% / 3); }`

To **align all three buttons** though leaving all them responsive I've wrapped my button into a div and used the following css:

```
.more-btn {
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
    margin-top: auto;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a media query to change the `flex-direction` when the screen resizes.

1. Add the following indie `.sub-offer` class.

```css
@media(max-width: 600px){
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

2. Add the following inside `h2` element.

```css
@media(max-width: 600px){
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image: Edit React and SCSS (forked)]

Comment: @Karina, check this out !!

Comment: thanks for contributing! It actually pushed all my columns on the left on 600px breakpoint. While what I need is to have the same width for 3 columns, and align content within them with each other

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really a good dev, but I can give it a try. What I do when I want to make things line up perfectly is use grid, so I tried adding it to .offer-container like this `.offer-container {display: grid; grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;}`. A working example is below. Though, since I'm new to helping people on StackOverflow or really StackOverflow in general, I'm sure I didn't do something right. for example, providing a solution to a different problem or fixing issues that you didn't as for. If you need a list of what I changed, you can see that here: `added } for sub-offer` `removed extra closing bracket on a{}` `separated &:hover to a:hover{}` `made <p> text white`. I hope this is the solution you were looking for if your problem hasn't already been fixed.

```css
.sub-offer {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    width:100px
}

.offer-container {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #2e2e3b, #0f1519);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 4.3em;
    width: 33%;
    text-align: center;
}

p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 2em;
    padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background: white;
    margin: 3em 0 2.5em 0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

a:hover {
    background: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<section class="sub-offer">
  <div class="offer-container">
    <div class="offer-up">
      <h2>Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png/09f/fff" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="offer-down">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Minus a
        rerum sapiente odit porro obcaecati fugit, maxime modi veritatis
        quis!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="more-btn">
      <a href="#">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="offer-container">
    <div class="offer-up">
      <h2>Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png/09f/fff" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="offer-down">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi
        perspiciatis voluptas qui iste, voluptatem atque ab rerum illum quia
        incidunt odio?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="more-btn">
      <a href="#">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="offer-container">
    <div class="offer-up">
      <h2>Lorem, ipsum.</h2>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x150.png/09f/fff" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="offer-down">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae
        vitae aut fugit dicta repellendus dolorem, quam, accusamus hic nemo
        ullam quod porro atque error?
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="more-btn">
      <a href="#">Lorem, ipsum.</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: hey! Thank you for your time! I have already solved my issue using flexbox and now it works fine. But as I can see your solution is also pretty relative to what I did!